# ColdFusion coercion of variables not clear

Tags: coldfusion, type-coercion

```
<cfset academic_year = "2012-13">
<cfoutput># academic_year gt "2009-10" #</cfoutput>
```

OUTPUTS NO

but if I change  academic_year VARIABLE to "2011-12" the Output is YES.

How is ColdFusion coercing the variable academic year?

Comment: What version CF are you using?  I tried it on both CF9 and CF10beta and evaluated to "No" both times.

Comment: Should be alphaneric comparison but it looks like it's evaluating your var.  are you sure you are not setting academic_year without the quotes as in in <cfset academic_year = 2012-13/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that the second one was just casting both sides to dates (incorrectly, but still... CF is "helpful" like that), so the answer is "correct".

I was more interested in why your first expression resulted in a "NO", because it can't be doing a date compare because the LHS is not construable as a date.  So it should be doing a string compare, and "2012-13" *is* greater than "2009-10", so the answer should be "YES" not "NO".

So I dug.  Check this code out:

```
<!--- literal.cfm --->
<cfset var1 = "2012-13">
<cfoutput>#var1 GT "2009-10"#</cfoutput><!--- this outputs: NO --->


<!--- variable.cfm --->
<cfset var1 = "2012-13">
<cfset var2 = "2009-10">
<cfoutput>#var1 GT var2#</cfoutput><!--- this outputs: YES--->
```

Note they're both comparing "2012-13" to "2009-10".

Why does it do this?  Because... if I am reading the decompiled code correctly... CF treats the literal "2009-10" in the first expression as a date (Oct 1, 2009)... then sees that it needs to be compared to a string ("2012-13" cannot be cast to a date), and seems to convert the date "Oct 1, 2009" back into a string ("40087"... the number of days between Dec 31, 1899 and Oct 1, 2009).  And "2012-13" is "less than" "40087" when doing a string compare.

Nowhere in the decompiled code for literal.cfm does "2009-10" exist.  The only reference is "40087.0D".  So CF looked at "2009-10", despite clearly being a string (quotes around it, etc), and said "yeah, that's a date", even though it's hard-coded into an expression where it cannot be used as a date.  Sigh.

So, anyway, that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Comment: Actually, no, I was mistaken: variable.cfm is actually just doing string compares on both.  but the explanation of literal.cfm still stands.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess. Perhaps "2011-12" and "2009-10" are being treated as a date with just year and month, so Dec 2011 is greater than Oct 2009. "2012-13" is not being treated as a date because its not a valid month.

What does a `cfdump` on academic_year show you?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but I would STRONGLY suggest that if you're going to compare dates that you do one of two things:

1. Use the [datecompare()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_26.html) function.
2. Use [`parseDateTime()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_11.html#134381) as Railo suggests in their [compatibility guide](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Language_And_Syntax_Differences).

It will save you from a lot of headaches like this and make life easier.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a comparison of two strings that look like "yyyy-mm" dates, but are in fact "yyyy-yy" strings.  You want to be doing a string comparison instead of a date comparison so you'll need to use an explicit string comparison function instead of letting ColdFusion infer your intentions.  The `Compare` function will accomplish this task for you.

```
<cfset academic_year = "2012-13">
<cfoutput>#Compare(academic_year, "2009-10")#</cfoutput>
```

- See [Compare documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f84.html) for the return values.
- See [Evaluation and type conversion issues](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f46.html) for why this is an issue.

If for some reason you still wanted to use the GT syntax, you can use `Val` to convert your two year string into a single year string.

```
<cfoutput># Val("2012-13") gt Val("2009-10") #</cfoutput>
```

Is treated as:

```
<cfoutput># "2012" gt "2009" #</cfoutput>
```

See [Val documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e64.html) for how that works.